# Fire Javascript event if <object> fails to load

Tags: javascript

I would like to fire an even if an `<object>` fails to load.

I know I can do this:

`<object>Some Error Happened</object>`

But I need to detect it with Javascript as well, and then fire some logic if the object fails.

That seems like an extremely impossible thing to do?

I have tried with:

```
document.querySelector('object').addEventListener('error', () => { alert('Something went wrong'); })
```

But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The error event is fired on a Window object:

```
window.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
    console.log(event)
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event

Comment: Error events don't bubble, if you want to catch them from `window` you need to add the `capture` flag to your listener. But here it won't do much anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a Chrome bug.

[Per specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-object-element%3Aattr-object-data-7), the `error` event should fire on the `<object>` element (and it does in Firefox) both if the URL parsing failed, or if the resource loading failed.
There is though some kind of a grey area where if the request didn't end in a network error, and *if the resource does not have associated Content-Type metadata*, then it will just silently fail...
This seems counter-intuitive and might require a specs bug.

Anyway, I think Chrome fails to recognize network errors as it should, so the solution is probably to open a [chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/) so they fix it. <sub>I added a comment on [BUG 853140](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=853140), let's see how it goes</sub>

The workaround is to use an `<iframe>` instead. `<object>` will probably get deprecated soon anyway.

Note that setting a `type` attribute to an unsupported type or just having it in the response's MIME type, Chrome will fire the event, but it still faces a new issue where it fires this event synchronously, even before we have time to attach any handler. So we have to force it to fire again by setting the `data` attribute again:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('object')
  .forEach( el => {
    el.onerror = e => console.log( "error", el );
    el.data = el.data; // force fire again
  } );
```

```html
<object data="/foo"></object> <!-- doesn't fire -->
<object data="/foo" type="image/svg+xml"></object> <!-- doesn't fire -->
<object data="/foo" type="foo/bar"></object> <!-- does fire -->
<object data="data:foo,"></object>  <!-- does fire -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kaiido. The reason why I choose to use `<object>` instead of `<iframe>` is that object re-sizes the embedded content to fit the object dimensions. most notable on safari in iPhone 4s where screen width is 320px and the html from the embedded URL may set dimensions greater. But I'll see if theres a workaround for this with iframe.